# How do I make impulse noise image efficiently using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I've been trying to create noisy image using the following piece of code:

```
def toImpulse(img, coef=1.2): # img - > 3dim numpy array, returns impulse image
    bmp = np.zeros(shape=(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            bmp[i][j] = sum(img[i][j]) / 3
```

Here I'm summing over the RGB channel and making the image single-channeled? I guess it can be written as numpy.sum()

```
    sum_ = 0
    max_ = np.amax(bmp)
    final = np.zeros(img.shape)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            sum_ += bmp[i][j]
            if sum_ >= coef * max_:
                final[i][j] = 1
                sum_ -= coef * max_
            else:
                final[i][j] = 0

    return final
```

But it occurred to be very slow in real-time video processing. How can I make it more efficient using NumPy? Here is the example of the function's work
[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U17yK.png)
[Noisy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atnqu.png)

Comment: The first function can simply be written as and should be much more efficient than the for loop: `return np.sum(axis=2) / 3`. I can't think of a better way for the second part of your code as it seems you are doing a conditional cumulative sum. In general, for efficient code you would want to avoid using explicit for loops and use numpy's functions.

Comment: Surely `np.mean(axis=2)` Maybe give `numba` a try for second part.

Comment: You can try use flat img (img.flat()) array with one counter.  And use variable k=coef*max_ out FOR.

Comment: You can also remove `else final[i][j]=0` since it is initialised with zeroes.

Comment: That code doesn’t generate any form of noise, there’s not even a random number being generated. Looks more like a form of dithering?

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of the algorithm please? It certainly looks like a type of dithering as Cris says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code takes 539ms on my machine. If I use Numpy to calculate the mean of the 3 colour channels and avoid writing zeroes to the output image because it is already initialised to zero like this:

```
def metoImpulse(img, coef=1.2):
    # Get mean of the 3 colour channels
    bmp = np.mean(img, axis=-1, dtype=np.float32)
    sum_ = 0
    max_ = np.amax(bmp)
    final = np.zeros_like(img[...,0])
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            sum_ += bmp[i][j]
            if sum_ >= coef * max_:
                final[i][j] = 1
                sum_ -= coef * max_
    return final
```

The time goes down from 539ms to 257ms. If I then use Numba by adding a decorator before my function:

```
@jit(parallel=True)
def metoImpulse(img, coef=1.2):
   # Get mean of the 3 colour channels
   bmp = np.mean(img, axis=-1, dtype=np.float32)
   sum_ = 0
   max_ = np.amax(bmp)
   final = np.zeros_like(img[...,0])
   for i in range(img.shape[0]):
      for j in range(img.shape[1]):
         sum_ += bmp[i][j]
         if sum_ >= coef * max_:
            final[i][j] = 1
            sum_ -= coef * max_
   return final
```

The time goes down from 257ms to 1.11ms.

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You second for loop can be replaced by `np.searchsorted` in cumsum of your array.

```
def toImpulse2(img, coef=1.2): # img - > 3dim numpy array, returns impulse image
    bmp = img.sum(axis=2)
    max_ = bmp.max() * coef
    cumsum = np.cumsum(bmp)
    repeats = int(cumsum[-1] / max_)
    final = np.zeros((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
    final[np.searchsorted(cumsum, np.arange(1, repeats + 1) * max_)] = 1
    return final.reshape(img.shape)
```

I use `img.sum()` instead of `img.mean()` to keep all calculations in integer type for precision. For big images there is little difference between this code and your code because it operates on float type.